# "Missing actual argument 'values' in call" when compiling old code

Tags: fortran

The code I'm trying to compile is named [gepol93](http://server.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/molecular_surface/gepol93/index.shtml) which was finished in 1994 with FORTRAN 77.

It's a program designed to compute some chemical properties of a molecule.

I tried to compile the file using the command `gfortran GEPOL93.FOR` but an error was raised:

```
EPOL93.FOR:598.72:

      IF(LPR)CALL STAT(NCOR)
                                                                        1
Error: Missing actual argument 'values' in call to 'stat' at (1)
```

I'm not familar with FORTRAN, and I guess that the code is too old to be compatible with the compiler on my computer.

What I'm certain about is that the code is definitely correct because it has never been modified by other people since 1994 (you can check this with `ls -l`) and many scholars are using it to conduct research nowadays.

But the question is how to compile the code into a .out file? Can anybody help me?

**In the first subroutine `PCOUNT`, `STAT` is called.**

```
      SUBROUTINE PCOUNT(NATOM,NCOR,KSURF,LPR)
C     -------------------------------------------------------------------
C     This prints general counters
C     -------------------------------------------------------------------

      IMPLICIT NONE

      LOGICAL FIRST
      LOGICAL LPR

      INTEGER*2 IUSE

      INTEGER*4 I,IUC
      INTEGER*4 J
      INTEGER*4 MC,MI
      INTEGER*4 NATOM,NCOR,NEWS

      REAL*4 RE
      REAL*4 XE
      REAL*4 YE
      REAL*4 ZE

      CHARACTER*5 KSURF

      PARAMETER (MC=100000,MI=6)

      COMMON/CSFE/XE(MC),YE(MC),ZE(MC),RE(MC),IUSE(MC)

      DIMENSION IUC(MI)

      IF(LPR)WRITE(6,'(/A)')' ===> Start Subroutine Pcount '

      NEWS=NCOR-NATOM

      IF(KSURF.EQ.'ESURF')THEN
         WRITE(6,'(3(A,I7/))')
     & ' Number of INITIAL coordinates          ',NATOM,
     & ' Number of NEW     coordinates          ',NEWS,
     & ' Number of TOTAL   coordinates          ',NCOR
      ELSE
         WRITE(6,'(A,I7/)')
     & ' Number of TOTAL coordinates            ',NCOR
      END IF      

      IF(LPR)THEN
      
        DO J=1,MI
        IUC(J)=0
        END DO

        DO I=1,NATOM
        J=IUSE(I)
        IUC(J)=IUC(J)+1
        END DO
     
        FIRST=.TRUE.
        DO J=1,MI
        IF(IUC(J).NE.0)THEN

          IF(FIRST)THEN
          FIRST=.FALSE.
          WRITE(6,'(A)')
     &          ' MORE INFORMATION ABOUT INITIAL SET OF COORDINATES'
          END IF

          WRITE(6,'(A,I2,A,I7)')
     &    ' Number of coordinates with IUSE ',J,'=',IUC(J)
        END IF
        END DO

        IF(KSURF.EQ.'ESURF')THEN

          DO J=1,MI
          IUC(J)=0
          END DO

          DO I=NATOM+1,NCOR
          J=IUSE(I)
          IUC(J)=IUC(J)+1
          END DO
     
          FIRST=.TRUE.
          DO J=1,MI
          IF(IUC(J).NE.0)THEN

              IF(FIRST)THEN
                FIRST=.FALSE.
                WRITE(6,'(A)')
     &        ' MORE INFORMATION ABOUT NEW SET OF COORDINATES'
              END IF

            WRITE(6,'(A,I2,A,I7)')
     &    ' Number of coordinates with IUSE ',J,'=',IUC(J)
          END IF
          END DO

        END IF

      IF(LPR)CALL STAT(NCOR)

      END IF
     
      RETURN
      END
```

```
      SUBROUTINE STAT(NCOR)
C     ------------------------------------------------------------- 
C     This prepares some statistics about the set of spheres
C     ------------------------------------------------------------- 
      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER*2 IUSE

      INTEGER*4 CT6,CT4
      INTEGER*4 I
      INTEGER*4 J
      INTEGER*4 MAXI,MC
      INTEGER*4 NCOR,NINT
      INTEGER*4 TMIN,TMAX

      REAL*4 C
      REAL*4 R1,R2,RE
      REAL*4 VINT
      REAL*4 XE
      REAL*4 YE
      REAL*4 ZE

      PARAMETER (MC=100000,MAXI=100)

      COMMON/CSFE/XE(MC),YE(MC),ZE(MC),RE(MC),IUSE(MC)

      DIMENSION CT4(MAXI),CT6(MAXI)

      WRITE(6,'(/A)')' ==> Start subroutine STAT'
      
      VINT=0.1
      TMIN=9000
      TMAX=0

      DO J=1,MAXI
      CT4(J)=0      
      CT6(J)=0      
      END DO

      DO I=1,NCOR
      C=RE(I)/VINT
      J=INT(C)+1
      IF(IUSE(I).EQ.6)THEN

        IF(J.LT.MAXI)THEN
          CT6(J)=CT6(J)+1
          TMAX=MAX(TMAX,J)
          TMIN=MIN(TMIN,J)
        END IF

      ELSE IF(IUSE(I).EQ.4)THEN 

        IF(J.LT.MAXI)THEN
          CT4(J)=CT4(J)+1
          TMAX=MAX(TMAX,J)
          TMIN=MIN(TMIN,J)
        END IF

      END IF
      END DO

      WRITE(6,'(A)')' RADII .GE. and .LT.    TYPE 4    TYPE 6'

      DO J=TMIN,TMAX
      R1=(J-1)*VINT
      R2=J*VINT
      WRITE(6,'(2F10.5,2I10)')R1,R2,CT4(J),CT6(J)
      END DO
 
      RETURN
      END
C
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of `subroutine STAT`. Be aware that many codes that have been used by researchers for many years are definitely incorrect. And modern compilers are better in finding these bugs.

Comment: See “man gfortran”. You need disable GNU extension and modern intrinsics. Probably “gfortran -std=legacy -pedantic -ffixed-form ...”

Comment: I have tried `gfortran -std=legacy -pedantic -ffixed-form GEPOL93.FOR` but errors and warnings were still raised.

Comment: You do NOT want pedantic!

Comment: Are those subroutines in a single file or in multiple files? I assume they are not in a module.

Comment: Serge3leo is correct with the intrinsics. However, rather then trying to disable them, you should fix your code by specifying `external stat` or by providing the interface block or rename STAT to something else.

Comment: They are in a single file named `GEPOL93.FOR`. The error said that I'm missing "values". I searched for "values" in the file but I didn't find any argument named "values".

Comment: This is because gfortran is trying to call https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/STAT.html instead of your own `STAT`. I say again: *"you should fix your code by specifying external stat or by providing the interface block or rename STAT to something else."*

Comment: OMG!  You saved my life! I renamed `STAT` to `mySTAT` and everything works! From my perspective, `STAT` is more like a built-in function like `sum()` in Python (only familiar with Python : ) ). Thanks to Vladimir F and Serge3leo.

Comment: @akarui, alternate You can rename STAT by preprocessor command-line options: `gfortran  -Wintrinsic-shadow -D"STAT(x)=GEPOL93_STAT(x)" gepol93/GEPOL93.FOR`. To check, you can run two commands: `nm -u a.out` will show dynamic links to the built-in functions, and `nm a.out | grep -i stat` will show the name of the renamed STAT() function.

Comment: @Serge3leo 2 Thanks! That's a quite useful information.

Comment: @akarui Could you please show how you ran the a.out generated with a test input?